# How do you get the error code from self.speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: self.recognitionRequest!, resultHandler: { (result, error)?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text

When using the ios [Speech library SFSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/1649883-recognitiontask) framework I want to specially handle some errors from recognitionTask. The problem is I can't figure out how to extract the error code. I've looked all around and I couldn't find an example or explanation in the doc how to get at it.

The signature:

func recognitionTask(with request: SFSpeechRecognitionRequest, 
       resultHandler: @escaping (SFSpeechRecognitionResult?, Error?) -> Void) -> SFSpeechRecognitionTask

Drilling down on Error says it's "protocol Error" which doesn't help very much.

When there is an error the local description show's there's a code:

2018-10-20 12:33:49.037515-0700 readsay[55123:12025377] error: Optional(Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)")

The problem is the error doesn't seem to contain anything recognizable as an error code:

[image]

My Swift is not very good. I assume the data is in the maps but there's no typing information I can find so that I can't extract them.

Can anyone please explain how to get to the error parameters?

Comment: The error Protocol has a default localisesDescription which can be used to get the error description https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error

Comment: Yes, that returns a string. I want the actual error code.

Comment: This works, but I'm not sure why, so I don't consider it an answer. let code = error.unsafelyUnwrapped._code

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Todd's suggestion does not work anymore...